# Install and manage python 2.7 and 3.11 in parallel in Linux (Parrot OS)

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-2.x

I have Parrot OS 6.5.0 in a VM and want to run python scripts that require python2 and scripts that require python3. Many of the scripts come with additional package requirements that I need to fulfill. I am the only user of the system. Some scripts might require sudo privileges (e.g. python webserver on port 80).

If I want to install packages via pip I get the infamous:

> $ python3 -m pip install <package_name>
> error: externally-managed-environment
> ...

I have been looking through several of the corresponding threads but I still do not know what the best option is for me. Very popular are the two options "sudo rm /usr/lib/python3.11/EXTERNALLY-MANAGED" and "--break-system-packages" which are not really intended solutions.

What am I supposed to do if I want to do it the correct way?
At the moment I have pyenv installed and python 3.11.2 and 2.7.18 are available.

> $ pyenv versions
> * system (set by /home/parrot/.pyenv/version)
> 2.7.18

Do I now need to use something like venv or virtualenv to create separate environments for all the scripts/programs I want to use to have them separate and not mix packages?

Comment: "*…which are not really intended solutions…What am I supposed to do if I want to do it the correct way?*" You don't have much choices. Either you screw your system and install packages into the global `site-packages/` or you use Python virtual environments (`venv`, `virtualenv`, `virtualenvwrapper`, `pyenv-virtualenv`). The end of the list of choices.

Comment: So my best option might be pyenv-virtualenv and then take it from there for every python program or at least ones that do not like each other. Then whenever I want to run something I activate and deactivate the corresponding environment?

Comment: Yep, exactly that!